# A variable can't assignment into 2

Tags: kotlin

I'm new to write kotlin. I meet a bug, and I don't know how to solve it.

This is part of the code:

```
for (j in 0..m - 1) {
    var b0 = a[j]
    var tt = j
    var b1: Int
    for (i in 0..n / m - 1) {
        tt = (tt + k) % n
        b1 = a[tt]
        a[tt] = b0
        if (b1 == 2)
            b0 = 2
        else
            b0 = b1
    }
}
```

When I debug it, I found something strange. Why `b0` can't assignment into 2.

[image]
[image]
[image]
This is all of the code:

```
import java.util.*

/**
 * Created by Yrh on 2015/12/3.
 */

fun ff(a: Int, b: Int): Int {
    var t = 1
    var i = 2
    var a1 = a
    var b1 = b
    while (i <= a1 && i <= b1) {
        t *= i
        a1 /= i
        b1 /= i
        i++
    }
    return t
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val scanner = Scanner(System.`in`)
    var a = IntArray(100)
    print("Input the number of data: ")
    val n = scanner.nextInt()
    print("Input the distant of moving: ")
    val k = scanner.nextInt()
    for (i in 0..n - 1)
        a[i] = scanner.nextInt()

    val m = ff(n, k)

    for (j in 0..m - 1) {
        var b0 = a[j]
        var tt = j
        var b1: Int
        for (i in 0..n / m - 1) {
            tt = (tt + k) % n
            b1 = a[tt]
            a[tt] = b0
            b0 = b1
        }
    }
    for (i in 0..n - 1) {
        print("${a[i]} ")
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you simplify the code a bit :D

Comment: And yes, there have been no bugs in Kotlin on that level of complexity for a long time if ever, so I would not expect it to be a bug.

Comment: @voddan :D I just begin to use kotlin yesterday, so I don't know how to write code in its style completely, I am still studying.

Comment: no problem, we all were there. Just help us to help you. Frankly speaking, even for a C code that looks like a mess :D So, if you hit the issue with less variables/assignments, that would help a lot

Comment: @voddan thx very much:)

Comment: @voddan And there is more question, can I write like this 'ff(var a:Int, var b:Int)', what should I write?

Comment: I don't really understand the goal that you are trying to reach. Why would you want to write this? If `ff` is a function, than this is not a valid syntax.

Comment: The only lang that I know provides such syntax is Pascal

Comment: @voddan That means the function parameter can not be a var?It must be a val?

Comment: No, you can't change/rewrite a functional parameter, because it's crazy unless you are writing Assembler.

Comment: @voddan I get it, thx again:) you're so friendly

Comment: @ You are welcome, I'am trying to do by best. Sorry if I discouraged you or anything, that was not what I mean.

Comment: @voddan I have found my error in the code,it works right now:)

Comment: @C_Y, what was the error in the code? Can you provide it as an answer below or accept an existing answer?

Comment: @C_Y can you add a note to the end of your question as to what was your bug so it is clear there is no issue in Kotlin and what the issue was instead with your code for those that find this question later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is right. Your inner loop is just finished and the outer one is continuing. 
And `b0` is newly created and initialized with `a[j]`, which is now 4 because `j` is 1 and `a[1]` is 4 which results in `b0` is 4.
Put your breakpoint into the `var b0 = a[j]` line and you'll see it.

Comment: But I am still in the inner loop ,you can see the highlight line is 'tt = (tt + k) % n'

Comment: yes, but you can also see that ```j``` incremented to 1 and in the previous step it was 0.